# Processes use different IPs for the same hostname

Tags: process, alias, hostname, hosts

On a Linux system, I need to deploy Java processes that have hostnames for external data and web server names hard-coded into the app, e.g. "mailserver" and "ftpserver".  When deploying on different hosts, we can of course use /etc/hosts to allow each deploy of this app use a different remote server for its "mailserver" or "ftpserver".

Now, we'd like to consolidate several application deployments onto one host.  However, each deployment still needs to point to it's own "mailserver" or "ftpserver", and this consolidated host's /etc/hosts cannot be used as it is shared by all the instances of the apps.

Is there a way to specify within a process' context a mapping of name-to-IP without using /etc/hosts or even DNS - since these are system-wide and shared by all processes?

I understand chroot would do the trick but am only willing to use that as a last resort.

Cheers,
Dog

Comment: Can you modify the Java code so that it determines server names in a way that is sensible?

Comment: Well, I'd rather use jails at that point.   I'm the sysadmin, not the developer.  I cannot for the life of me understand what they thought when they wrote it this way (no connection pools, no .conf file to define the external hosts and URLS, etc.)

Comment: If feasible, change software. Someone who does all the simple things badly, even where it's well understood how to do them well, probably does complicated things at least as badly.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily store configuration information in a deployment specific file and load it at runtime using [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html).

Comment: Thanks, I should add that I cannot touch the code.  I understand that the code itself could and should be made more modular, and not so "stuck" on hostname resolution for hard-coded names within the app.